# Open a pop-up window of fixed size using Flask

Tags: javascript, html, flask

when i click an html button, I want to open a new window of size 800 by 600 using the target html tag and Flask render_template function. I have the following code

**HTML & Javascript**

```html
 <form id="myForm" action="/open_window" method="post" target="newWindow">
        <input type="submit" value="Open New Window" onclick="openNewWindow()">
    </form>

    <script>
        function openNewWindow() {
            // Define the window size
            var width = 800;
            var height = 600;

            // Calculate the position to center the window
            var leftPosition = (screen.width - width) / 2;
            var topPosition = (screen.height - height) / 2;

            // Open a new window with specified size and centered
            window.open('', 'newWindow', 'width=' + width + ', height=' + height + ', left=' + leftPosition + ', top=' + topPosition);
        }
    </script>
```

**Flask**

```py
@app.route('/open_window', methods=['POST'])

def open_window():
    # Perform any necessary operations here before opening the window
    return render_template('evidence.html')
```

This opens up a new tab but not a pop up window of fixed size. Am I missing something?

Please note I am using a chrome browser